# Parse code into two column table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to parse a cvss score into a data table. Starting with a code that looks something like this: `AV:N/AC:H/PR:L/UI:R/`

I need to produce a table that looks like this

```
   Metric   Attribute
1  AV       N
2  AC       H
3  PR       L   ...etc
```

I have a function that creates one column with each Metric-Attribute pair, however, I'm not sure how to separate them into separate columns. Does anyone have any ideas here?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
        WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )


    SELECT 'Metric:Attribute' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around I was able to work out this solution.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ParseCvss]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX('/',@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX('/',@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0        
    )


    SELECT 'Metric' = left(SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos), CHARINDEX(':', SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)) - 1),
           'Value' = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos), CHARINDEX(':', SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0), LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)) + 1, Len(SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0), LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)))
    FROM Split      
)
```